# UiViewcontroller with Button

Tags: ios4

I have 2 viewcontroller and in that one controller  having a button, now i want when i pressed the button it will show the next viewcontroller without using navigation and modalviewcontrollers...

How can i do this plz help  me....

Comment: I've updated my answer and I'm pretty sure at least one of the methods will work for you. If they don't let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present a controller's view without using navigation or modal view controller, you can simply add the controller's view as a subview of the window.

In the controller that will present the next controller you would do the following:

```
[self.view.window addSubview:controller.view];
```

**EDIT:** Try the following:

```
[((YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window addSubview:controller.view]
```

This assumes that your app delegate has a window property.

**EDIT 2:** Here's another option.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:controller.view];
```